# How to dismiss a keyboard from textview programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview

Is there any way to hide or do not show the keyboard without calling `resignFirstResponder` in iOS? I know different method to hide keyboard, first one is to make the textview non editable, or using

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textview
{
    [textview resignFirstResponder];
}
```

but in my case these method will not be works out, becz I just want to dismiss or hide the keyboard only, but need the editing in textview. I have a textview which contains some text, when I tap the sentence it need to be selected, I have done that selection part nicely, but when I write above keyboard dismissal method in my project, the selection of the tapped sentence doesn't appear,.is there any method to o this.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to do. You say you want to be able to edit the textview, but do not want the keyboard? How do you let the user edit then? Do you want the keyboard to ever show up or not?

Comment: @JPHribovsek i don't want to showup keyboard ever.why down vote for this question?

Comment: I didn't down vote your question, just trying to help...

Comment: @JPHribovsek ok thanks..i got the solution from Vignesh.this is a really nice solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Textfield's selection will remain only when you are in editing mode. When you resign your first responder your selection disappears too.

To avoid bringing keypad in editing mode, you can change the input view. For example , look at the code,

```
    textview.inputView = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

This brings a custom input view and it is not visible.

Comment: where did i put this above code?in did selection method of texview?

Comment: When you create your textview.

Comment: ,but i create this textview in IB...so can i put his in ViewDidLoad for example...mainTextview.inputview =[[UIView alloc]init];

Comment: agin you helps me once more,,hehe,thanks loootttttt..it woks for me..here is no were in google that we can dismiss the keyboard in this way.thanks again

Comment: @stackiphone. Welcome once again!. Technically i have not dismissed the keyboard I just presented an input view with no frames set(CGRectZero).

Comment: oh thats a great ideaaa,and i don't know why these people down voted this question,this is a vey useful question with answer for anyone.

Comment: @stackiphone. I think it is down voted since, it is quite unorthodox to make textview editable without having a input view to support editing.Also it is bit difficult to understand what you want exactly with out previous knowledge about the problem. Rephrasing the question to make it more clear may make your question up voted!. Nevertheless it is an interesting question!.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
self.textView.editable = NO;
```

Try this

```
NSRange selection = [yourTextView.text rangeOfString:yourTextView.text]; 
if( selection.location != NSNotFound ){ yourTextView.selectedRange = selection; }
```

It will remove the keyboard from the textview. Hope it helps.

Comment: no it won't workout for me,plz chi the question,i just want the selection of the textview without keyboard appear